# Connecting callback to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, callback

I am calling a library function which also need a callback function as its only argument. It is time consuming function and the callback is called frequently to pass messages to the client (my application) to display. The problem is I want to copy the message and pass it onto the main thread for display but because it is callback function, I see no other way but to use globals to do that and that's what I am trying to avoid/make better.

The callback is static member function of my `CTestDlg` which alrady has  `m_hWnd` member where I want to post the messages. However for the sake of callback I have yet defined another static g_hWnd member so my callback can access it and post message to it. This part doesn't look very nice to me but my callback routine is collecting messages wonderfully.

My callback function is the following

```
void CTestDlg::OnNotify (int code, const char * msg)
{
    char * message  =  NULL; // to copy the message

    message = new char[ strlen( msg) + 1 ]();

    strcpy_s( message, strlen(msg) +1, msg );


    PostMessageA( g_hWnd, ID_NOTIFY_MSG, code, (LPARAM) message );

}
```

I am running the library call in a separate thread and because it is callback to that function, it also runs in the same thread. Is there a better way to change hand in this callback function and pass the message to main thread or a particularly window to display?

Answer (score 0):

If your callback is a *static* method, it has no access to instance data, so you *must* store your state data (the main window handle, in your case) in a static or global variable.

You can move the handle from a global variable to a static `CTestDlg::s_hWnd` variable.